# Ошибка: NameError: name 'open_read' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

При компиляции данного кода выдает такую ошибку:

> NameError: name 'open_read' is not defined

Объясните пожалуйста, в чем заключается моя ошибка?

```
class File:

    def __init__(self):
        self.path='input\example.txt'

    def open_read(self): # функция открывает и считывает файл
        file = open(self.path)
        content = file.read()
        print(content)

open_read()
```

Comment: `open_read` - метод объекта класса `File`, т.е. находящийся в его (классе) пространстве имен. Обращение возможно через экземпляр класса: `File().open_read()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо либо вызвать этот метод внутри класса и для этого сделать еще 4 пробела в строчке с вызовом, либо вызвать его вне класса с указанием имени класса: `File.open_read()`.